# How to get DateTime.Now , starting from an offset

Tags: datetime, .net-core, offset

I have  a scenario where i need the `DateTime.Now` property to start with a given date and then on next calls to just continue from there.

I need to be able to initialize `Now` lets say with  `1.07.1990` and then on each call of  `DateTime.Now` to calculate me how much time has passed.

```
var offsetedNow=DateTime.Parse("01/07/1990 08:00:30");
//lets say i call the next line after 3 seconds
var newOffsetedNow=F(offsetedNow); // 01/07/1990 08:00:33
//i call it again after 1 minute
var lastNow=F(newOffsetedNow);// 01/07/1990 08:01:33
```

Basically from a given date  i need to "simulate" that time flows regularly.

Comment: That is not possible. You need to use a wrapper around `DateTime.Now` instead. Consider looking into `Stopwatch` instead/also.

Comment: I indeed need a wrapper but how could this be done ?

Comment: var offset = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse("01/07/1990 08:00:30");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            var offsetedNow = DateTime.Now - offset;

Comment: I would need something continous since i will use it just as a `DateTime.Now`.Probably a long running `Task` with a `StopWatch` as `Christian.K` pointed out

Comment: hm. DateTime.Parse("01/07/1990 08:00:30").Add(new TimeSpan(sw.ElapsedTicks)); //sw is stopwatch

Comment: @xSx Your first solution suits me.I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.
Light:

```
var offset = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse("01/07/1990 08:00:30");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); 
var offsetedNow = DateTime.Now - offset;
```

Hard:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
sw.Stop();
var offsetedTime = DateTime.Parse("01/07/1990 08:00:30").Add(new TimeSpan(sw.ElapsedTicks));
```

Comment: Careful, `TimeSpan` ticks and `Stopwatch` ticks are not the same.  Use `.Add(sw.Elapsed)` rather than `.Add(new TimeSpan(sw.ElapsedTicks))`